# how to implement validations by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I implemented  the validation for email,new and confirm password in js,the validations which i wrote are not working.could any one please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Please put your incorrect code here , somebody can correct it for you

Comment: Did you check my answer ? let me know  if you are  facing any problem

Comment: For email validation at client side...you can do `<input type="email" name="email">` specifying `type` to be of `email`..

Comment: You can check my updated answer , in that i had included a jsfiddle demo,it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email validation you can use reguler expressions

Exampe :

```
function Emailvalidation(email) 
{
    var check= /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return check.test(email);
}
```

the above program validates

**string@string.string** format

**Note** : Client side validation is not a good approach,Javascript can be easily disabled , so it is better to use server side validations

For password validation you can write a function in onclick event of submit button there compare two text box values.

Example Validation with password, mobile number, email **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xrnLzw65/)**

Comment: thank you for your solutions Saru and Arunprasanth

Comment: @MythilyM is it working ? is it your problem is solved with the corresponding answer then you can mark it as a right answer

Comment: ya it is working but the problem is validation of email along with new password and confirm password is not working properly.here is my code.........

Comment: @MythilyM you have any submit button or anything like that ? then you have to include your all validation inside that , not make it different

Comment: @MythilyM edit your question and put your code there

Comment: @MythilyM or you want to validate when user leaves the text field then use  onblur event  it occurs when an object loses focus.

Comment: thank you ....... my validations are working.......on server,i could implement my code in jsp page .to show my code space is not sufficient in comment box.

Answer (score 0):

I give sample field and js for validation

```
        <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size=18 maxlength=50 required onblur="javascript:myFunction(this.value)">
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size=18 maxlength=50 required>
        <label>Confirm Password</label><span id='message'></span><input type="password" name="cpass" id="cpass" size=18 maxlength=50 required/>


     js
      <script> 
      function myFunction(em) {
        var x = document.forms["profile"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
       if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
       alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      document.getElementById("email").value = "";
      return false;
     exit();
     }
     }
     </script>
    <!-- for password validation use jquery -->
    <script      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $('#pass, #cpass').on('keyup', function () {
     if ($('#pass').val() == $('#cpass').val()) {
       $('#message').html('<img src="image/tick.png" width=15px height=15/>').css('color', 'green');  
     } 
    else{ 
      $('#message').html('<img src="image/delete1.png" width=15px height=15/>').css('color', 'red'); 
       }
   });
 </script>
```

I hope this will help you